# create-react-app Component in different folder than project errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I've created a new app using `create-react-app React` and a few apps can reuse the same Components.
So I've create a structure like this

```
- App1
- App2
- App3
- Utils
  - Components
```

When I'm trying to load Utils/Components from within an app, it first gave me the `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`-error.
I've changed the filetypes from `.js` to `.jsx` and now it's giving me the following error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': 
The tag name provided ('/static/media/TeamSidebar.2e3fe8e5.jsx') is not 
a valid name.
```

package.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
        "react": "^16.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
        "react-moment": "^0.6.5",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
        "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
        "utils": "file:../utils"
 },
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Components} from 'utils';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const {TeamSidebar} = Components;

        return (
            <TeamSidebar teams={teamsList}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create-React-App's project by default should look like this:

```
 my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

**src** folder contains all the specific components that make up your application. In your case, you have to place all of you files/folders inside **src** folder like this:

Try importing like this:

```
   src/
    -App1
    -App2
    -App3
    -Utils
     -Components ex:(User.js)
    ...
    ...
```

when you want to **import** any files from **Utils** you can do it by this way:

```
import NameYourFile '../Utils/WhatEverFile';
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It shows this `Module not found: You attempted to import ../../utils which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.`

Comment: Is your app inside src folder or not ?

Comment: Yes, just not the utils components (the shared ones)

Comment: you have to place all of you files/folders inside src because it is defined as an entry directory within webpack!

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a lot, let me know! @CreasolDev

Comment: A requirement is that they are 3 separate instances of create-react-app and this way, all 3 apps are within 1 instance of create-react-app. In all other cases, I think this would be a way to go, but since it's a requirement, I can't do it like this. But thanks!